# Interact with wab.exe example?

Tags: windows, visual-studio

I am a beginner and want to know How to access and modify wab.exe in windows? Using which tool can i interact with my wab.exe and can access its functions? any example would be appreciated.

Comment: What is `wab.exe` in the first place?

Comment: Wab.exe is a process used by windows to store addresses, contact details and e-mail addresses.
http://www.processlibrary.com/en/directory/files/wab/24781/

Comment: I want to know the very basic steps to interact with this file. which tool would i have to install and how can i be able interact with it

Comment: There's no such tool in Windows 10. It's been replaced by the `People` app

Comment: Or rather, WAB was replaced by [Windows Contacts](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff800913%28v=vs.85%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396) in Windows Vista, 10 years ago. This was then replaced by the `People` app in Windows 10. `Windows Contacts` is still available. If you type `wab` in the run dialog the `Contacts` folder will open. You shouldn't depend on it though, it can be removed at any time since it's deprecated

Comment: Thank you for the information. But, I am ok with that deprecated process. Kindly guide me how to interact with wab.exe? (in case of windows 7 or windows 8)

Comment: You *can't*. It's not there anymore. In Windows 7 you have to use Windows Contacts.

Comment: This is the link to the [Windows Address Book SDK](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms629361%28v=vs.85%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396). In any case, Windows features are installed from the `Programs and Features` applet in older versions. You can't install the features by themselves nor download them.